# How to merge two hashmaps on Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

How can I merge two hashmap variables, for example `map1` and `map2`?

I have tried `(merge map1 map2)`, but I got the following exception:

> ClassCastException java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, obviously because `java.util.HashMap` is not clojure map. You probably get `map1` or `map2` (or both) executing some java code?

so in this case you should first convert them to clojure maps like this, for example:

`(merge (into {} map1) (into {} map2))`

this should work.

also read this one: [Clojure: working with a java.util.HashMap in an idomatic Clojure fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665103/clojure-working-with-a-java-util-hashmap-in-an-idomatic-clojure-fashion)

Comment: right you are, but i just wanted to emphasize the conversion idea