# Clojure. How can I sum all the value of the map

Tags: clojure

I have a return hashmap from firestore as below:

```
#object[java.util.HashMap 0x163df674 {reference=NEW_USER, type=Promotion, includedScans=100}]
#object[java.util.HashMap 0x140a8085 {reference=NEW_USER, type=Promotion, includedScans=50}]
```

......

I would like to sum all the "includedScans" of them in Clojure

Expected result: 150

Can someone please help!
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried already some code you could share?  At first glance this looks like a two part question: how to extract the value you are interested and next how to sum it up.  Both answered already one ore another time here.  So maybe you have some special problem in regard firestore?

Answer (score 1):

**1 - using `java.util.HashMap`**

given n maps,

```
user=> (def map1 (java.util.HashMap. {:reference "user1" :type "Promotion" :included-scans 100}))
#'user/map1

user=> (def map2 (java.util.HashMap. {:reference "user1" :type "Promotion" :included-scans 50}))
#'user/map2
```

map over vector of hash-maps,

```
user=> (map #(:included-scans %) [map1 map2]) ;; #() represents a function on each element
(100 50)

;; alternative way is
user=> (map :included-scans [map1 map2])
(100 50)
```

sum the values using `reduce` function,

```
user=> (reduce + (map #(:included-scans %) [map1 map2]))
150
```

Note that above map is `java.lang.HashMap`, clojure has its own data-structure as well called `clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap`

**2 - Using `clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap`,**

given n number of maps,

```
user=> (def map1 (hash-map :reference "user1" :type "Promotion" :included-scans 100))
#'user/map1

user=> (def map2 (hash-map :reference "user1" :type "Promotion" :included-scans 50))
#'user/map2
```

You simply can map over them and get the required key which is `:included-scans` in your case,

```
user=> (map #(:included-scans %) [map1 map2])
(100 50)
```

Then to sum up using `reduce` function,

```
user=> (reduce + (map #(:included-scans %) [map1 map2]))
150
```

### references

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-map

[Clojure: working with a java.util.HashMap in an idiomatic Clojure fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1666053/432903)

Comment: Since `keywords` are function of maps to their values, writing `(map #(:scans %) [map1 map2])` is equivalent to `(map :scans [map1 map2])`

Comment: @prayagupd can you advise me to write the unit test for this?

    `(defn get-includedScans-value
      [snapshot]
      (-> snapshot
        .getData
        (.get "includedScans")))`

I have define the map as you told:
`(def map1 (java.util.HashMap. {:reference "user1" :type "Promotion" :included-scans 100}))`

But it keeps saying that `actual: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: getData for class java.util.HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can follow the code samples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1666053) to convert the Java-Map into an Clojure-Map.</s>

```
user> (java.util.HashMap. {:foo :bar})
#<HashMap {:foo=:bar}>

user> (into {} (java.util.HashMap. {:foo :bar}))
{:foo :bar}
```

After converting, the summarizing could be done like this:

You can use the Java-Hashmap like any other Map in Clojure (see comments). The summarizing could be done like this:

```
user> (reduce (fn[s m] (+ s (get m "includedScans"))) 0 [map1 map2 ...])
```

Comment: You actually dont need to convert your maps at all, `(reduce (fn[s m] (+ s (get m :foo))) 0 [(java.util.HashMap. {:foo 4}) (java.util.HashMap. {:foo 3})])` works just fine like this as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transduce` to do this in an efficient, non-lazy manner.

```
(transduce (map #(get % "includedScans" 0)) + 0 [map1 map2 ...])
```