# Using Java hashmaps in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am new to Clojure. I am trying to use java hashmap in clojure. I am passing a java hashmap to Clojure. The map is- {0=Goa, 1=Delhi, 2=Mumbai}. When I am trying to use the clojure functions on this map I am not getting the expected output. In contrast to this when I am iterating over this map it is giving the expected output.

```
Example
   (println(get map 0)) is giving nil




(doseq [[key value] map
      (println value)) is giving the expected output.

        Output-Goa
               Delhi
               Mumbai
```

Can somebody please expain me why is this happening?

Comment: Please be mindful about how you tag your questions.  Given your question is not about [tag:java], attracting Java experts to your question is not going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You really should google a bit to find pre-existing answers like this one:   [Clojure: working with a java.util.HashMap in an idiomatic Clojure fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665103/clojure-working-with-a-java-util-hashmap-in-an-idiomatic-clojure-fashion)

You can then see a simple answer:

```
(def data {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})

(def java-map (java.util.HashMap. data))
(def clj-map  (into {} java-map))
```

which gives us:

```
java-map  => <#java.util.HashMap {:b 2, :c 3, :a 1}>
clj-map   => <#clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap {:b 2, :c 3, :a 1}>
```

and looping:

```
  (doseq [[k v] clj-map]
    (println (format "key=%s  val=%s" k v)) )
```

with result:

```
key=:b  val=2
key=:c  val=3
key=:a  val=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your map is named "map" which is also a Clojure function.  Try it like this:

```
(def my-map {0 "Goa" 1 "Delhi" 2 "Mumbai"})
```

Which then will work like this:

```
(println (get my-map 0))
```

Note that it still returns nil, since there is nothing else after the (println) form but it does print the value of the 0 in the map, which is "Goa".

Comment: While it's true that you shouldn't use `map` as the name of your map, if you try it on the REPL you should just get a warning like `WARNING: map already refers to: #'clojure.core/map in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/map`. It would cause bizarre behavior if you then naively try to use the normal Clojure `map` function, but wouldn't cause the specific issue described here.

Comment: @BenSchmidt Thanks for the clarification.  It's not totally clear to me where his "map" came from since that part of the code is missing from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(def input-map {0 "Goa" 1 "Delhi" 2 "Mumbai"})

(map (fn[[k v]] (print "key " k " value " k)) input-map)
```

[[k v]] for function let you access key and value for each entry

```
(map print input-map)
```

here map entry will be passed as parameter to print